# CUDA - Is there a way to preserve the relativity of pointers to other classes in the same memory copied to the GPU

Tags: cuda

I am working with code where the host memory has pointers to other regions of memory that will be copied by the cudaMemcpy call.

Is there a way to do something like in the following code sample (which doesn't work), to make it so that the elements in device memory's pointers correspond to other elements in device memory, like they do in host memory? Or is there a 'best practice' way of handling this type of problem?

Otherwise, I guess I would have to store relative offsets instead of pointers.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    A* nextA = nullptr;
    int val = 5;
};
__global__ void kernel(A* d) {
    d[0].nextA->val = 20;
}
int main() {
    A* h = new A[2];
    h[0].nextA = &h[1];

    A* d;
    cudaMalloc(&d, sizeof(A) * 2);
    cudaMemcpy(d, h, sizeof(A) * 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel << <1, 1 >> > (d);
    cudaMemcpy(h, d, sizeof(A) * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("val=%d\n",h[1].val);    //hoping this would be 20
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to... make it so that the elements in device memory's pointers correspond to other elements in device memory, like they do in host memory?

Well, you could use CUDA's [unified memory feature](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) (available since CUDA 6), using which you have device-side memory accessible from the host-side and vice-versa. With Pascal and later GPUs, you get virtual memory [paging](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/beyond-gpu-memory-limits-unified-memory-pascal/) as well, so you can allocate more than the GPU actually has and still access it.

Of course, doing this obliviously will hurt your performance. Doing this very carefully will still hurt your performance, somewhat, and it's difficult for me to say how much, since it depends on the use case, plus I'm not a UVM+paging kind of a guy.

> Or is there a 'best practice' way of handling this type of problem?

Well, you could use offsets instead of pointers. Your related pointers likely share some kind of common "arena" of memory; and if they don't already, you can probably define one (within which they're allocated to begin with). Now, stop storing pointers. Rather, store the arena's base address somewhere common, and store offsets from there. Then allocate the arena's size's worth of memory on the device and copy what you need. On the device side you can continue using the same code, but with the device-side rather than the host-side arena address.

... but actually, that's probably not the real answer. The real answer is likely: **If you're dereferencing pointers a lot, then your kernel is faulty; rewrite it**. It is very likely mis-designed for exploiting the GPU's hardware, and will run slowly.